# CodeIgniter: Weird echo of $config coming back when I load Email Library

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, autoload

Version info: CI version 1.7.2 - PHP 5.3.1 - Apache2 - Mac OSX 10.6.3

For some reason, when I load CI's email library, either in my controller, or in autoload.php, it automatically and immediately echoes the config info like so:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE
```

If I autoload the email library in autoload.php, it is echoed before anything else in my source/page. If I call it explicitly within my controller, it's echoed at that exact point.

I'm stumped, never seen that before. Any ideas on how to surpress/eliminate?

Loading the library in autoload:
`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','encrypt','email');`

Loading the library in the controller:
`$this->load->library('email');`

Comment: You should post the code you're using to load the lib.

Comment: Added my lib loading syntax to orig post. Pretty basic.

Comment: This might sound strange, but try setting a header() after the autoload code has run, the "output has already been started" error that gets generated may give you the line/file of the offending "echo" statements.  Perhaps someone added a debug line that broke something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems rather odd. I'm using this library succesfully with the same CI version.

What is also odd is that the config values being printed are not the CI defaults!

Where are you setting the config values?

Are you definitely sure you're not setting the config anywhere else? e.g. in a config file in your config folder and accidently printing them here? This would explain both why the values are not defaults and they're only appearing when the class is loaded since it checks for a config file first.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me to my config folder which had email.php in it with those values. Something from a long time ago I guess. I removed the contents of that file and the issue went away. However, I believe that file was implemented properly.

Comment: Perhaps `email.php` was missing a `<?php` at the start?

Comment: @gnarf - Bingo! That was it. Ah the joy of multiple devs in my code. I'm accepting rbaker86's answer as it put us down the right path.

added <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

to the top and it's all good. Thanks!